# custom dropdown vuex, how to select innertext or innerHTML

Tags: vue.js, vuex, dropdown, selected

I am working on a ui component where values are coming from a store. I am trying to get the list item in the dropdown
@click="getRoute(i, $event.target.innerHTML)

to appear on the page, so far the click event targets all the routestart instead of only [image]the one which was clicked

Any help much appreciated, I know I am missing a trick here, Also appreciate all the help people have given before

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" id="passenger-type">
    <div class="dropdown__decoration">
      <label class="dropdown__label">Route</label>
      <ul
        v-show="selectedJourneyroutes"
        class="dropdown__selected"
        @click="isOpen = true"
        @input="isOpen = true"
      >
        <li v-for="(a, i) in selectedJourneyroutes" :key="i">
          {{ a.routestart }} 
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="dropdown__types" v-if="isOpen">
        <li
          class="dropdown__li"
          v-for="(journeyroute, i) in journeyroutes"
          :key="i"
        >
            <div class="dropdown__route-container" @click="getRoute(i, $event.target.innerHTML)">
                <div class="dropdown__route-detail">
                    <span>{{ journeyroute.route }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown__route-detail">
                    <span>{{ journeyroute.routestart }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown__route-detail">
                    <span>{{ journeyroute.routeend }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    journeyroutes: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.journeyroutes;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("selectedJourneyroute", value);
      }
    },

    selectedJourneyroutes: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.selectedJourneyroute;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("selectedJourneyroute", value);
      }
    },

  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    },

    handleClickOutside(evt) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(evt.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
      }
    },

    getRoute(i, innerHTML) {
        const newJourneyRoutes = [...this.journeyroutes];
        newJourneyRoutes[i, innerHTML]
        this.$store.commit("updateSelectedJourneyRoutes", newJourneyRoutes);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you trying to use Vue to read data out of HTML that you put into the HTML with vue? Why not just get `journeyroutes[i].route`?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the data inside Vue and you're using it to populate the HTML DOM. Why try to get it back out of the DOM?

Instead, just use the Vue data object:

```
<template>
...
      <ul
        v-show="selectedJourneyroutes"
        class="dropdown__selected"
        @click="isOpen = true"
        @input="isOpen = true"
      >
        <li v-for="(a, i) in selectedJourneyroutes" :key="i">
          {{ a.routestart }} 
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="dropdown__types" v-if="isOpen">
        <li
          class="dropdown__li"
          v-for="(journeyroute, i) in journeyroutes"
          :key="i"
        >
            <div class="dropdown__route-container" @click="getRoute(i)">
                ...
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    ...

    getRoute(targ) {
        let routeDetails = this.journeyroutes[targ]
        const newJourneyRoutes = [...this.journeyroutes];
        newJourneyRoutes[i, routeDetails]
        this.$store.commit("updateSelectedJourneyRoutes", newJourneyRoutes);
    }
  },

  ...
};
</script>
```

Or you could pass the entire object back since it's easily available in the iteration. Either way, it's already in memory as a computed value as part of the Vue component so just grab that data.

```
@click="getRoute(journeyroute)
```

Comment: Hi Bryce, thanks for getting back. That dosent really work. The click event still populates all the options instead of just the row that has been clicked. 

To be honest its a weird design that I am going to push back on. It should be simpler and use native form elements which would make things easier. 

The designer wants basically three separately styled elements within an <option> tag,,,,, which is prob just mad.

Comment: I might not be understanding what you're trying to do then, but yeah it does seem overly complicated. Is your click event on the wrong DOM element?  Maybe it should go on the `<li>` and not on the `<div>`?